# TikZ picture with text right of it

Tags: tikz-pgf

I have a picture created in TikZ and I have some explanation that I want to place to the left of it, preferably that the explanation takes about the same space as my figure (vertical). How do I do it?

My example:

```
\begin{tikzpicture}[zw/.style={minimum height=6.5mm}]
\node[zw]   (R)                 {$R$};
\node[zw]   (RI)    [right=of R]    {$R/I$};
\node[zw]   (S) [below=of R]    {$S$};
\node[zw]   (I) [left=of R]     {$I$};

\draw[->] (R.east) -- node[above] {$\pi$} (RI.west);
\draw[->] (R.south) -- node[left] {$f$} (S.north);
\draw[->, dashed] (RI.south) -- node[anchor=north west]{$\exists!\tilde{f}$} (S.north east);
\draw[right hook->] (I.east) -- (R.west);
\end{tikzpicture}
Sei $S$ ein Ring, und $f:R\to S$ ein Ringhomomorphismus, sodass $I\subset\ker f$. Dann gibt es einen eindeutigen Ringhomomorphismus $\tilde f: R/I \to S$ sodass $f = \tilde f \pi$.`
```

Comment: Hi and welcome, you can use minipages to do that quite easily.

Comment: If you tell me what tikzlibray i need, i'll make the example complete.

Comment: Please, make the example compilable.

Comment: Is this text to be part of the whole text or as a sort of "explanation caption"? Please, provide the full MWE.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[image: cmeierMinipages]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}
\begin{minipage}{.45\linewidth}
    Sei $S$ ein Ring, und $f:R\to S$ ein Ringhomomorphismus,
    sodass $I\subset\ker f$. Dann gibt es einen eindeutigen
    Ringhomomorphismus $\tilde f: R/I \to S$ sodass $f =
    \tilde f \pi$.`
\end{minipage}\hfill
\begin{minipage}{.45\linewidth}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \draw (0,0) rectangle (2,2);
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{minipage}
\end{document}
```